# Using access to refer to objects within access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a basic table in access with several populated fields. I would like to explore if there is a way, preferably through the GUI (or maybe through SQL), to add a field containing the name of the table itself. I see only the following data formats for fields: Short text, Long text, number, Date/time, Currency, Autonumber, Yes/No, OLE Object, Hyperlink, Attachment and Calculated. There is nothing pertaining to data object parameters themselves such as table, field or query names or parameters...

Comment: It is not clear what you want. Please explain a little more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the meta data of the database via VBA (Visual Basic for Applications) macros.

For example, this can show all table names:

```
Option Compare Database

Public Sub Test()
    Dim database As DAO.database
    Dim tableDef As DAO.tableDef
    Set database = CurrentDb
    For Each tableDef In database.TableDefs
            MsgBox tableDef.Name
    Next
End Sub
```